# Google Chrome much slower when using file:// instead of http://

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html, http

I occasionally have html files stored locally that I need to view.  Opening them in Google Chrome as `file:///path/to/file.html` is excruciatingly slow.  If I serve them up over http like `http://path/to/file.html` they load instantly.  Other browsers like Firefox load them instantly whether using `file://` or `http://`.

Is there a setting in Chrome that's causing this?  Is this a bug or a "feature"?